# select with case statement give me error in as

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, case

i write a store procedure with case

```
SELECT TOP(10000) ORDER,ORDERID,CLIENTNUM,

CASE WHEN ExpArrvDate IS NOT NULL AND ActArrvDate IS NULL THEN 'In Transit'
ELSE
  CASE WHEN ActArrvDate IS NULL   THEN 'NOT COME' 
ELSE
 CASE WHEN DRV1NUM IS NOT NULL THEN 'WILL Come'
ELSE
  CASE WHEN PICKEDUP IS NOT NULL THEN 'Picked By JOHN '
ELSE
  CASE WHEN DROPTIME IS NOT NULL THEN 'Dropped Off'
AS OrderDeatils

FROM CTRTABle
```

what i am doing wrong in this statement in can you please help me

Comment: You need to `END` each `CASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `END` each `CASE` as

```
SELECT TOP(10000) ORDER,ORDERID,CLIENTNUM,

    CASE WHEN ExpArrvDate IS NOT NULL AND ActArrvDate IS NULL THEN 'In Transit'
    ELSE
      CASE WHEN ActArrvDate IS NULL   THEN 'NOT COME' 
    ELSE
     CASE WHEN DRV1NUM IS NOT NULL THEN 'WILL Come'
    ELSE
      CASE WHEN PICKEDUP IS NOT NULL THEN 'Picked By JOHN '
    ELSE
      CASE WHEN DROPTIME IS NOT NULL THEN 'Dropped Off' 
    END END END END END -- Added line. Added END for each CASE
    AS OrderDeatils

    FROM CTRTABle
```